# When Logged out, one blog shows - logged in, all blogs show

Tags: html, wordpress, blogs

I've coded this Wordpress site but I'm finding difficulties with the blog area.  Only one blog shows in the blog section but with I am logged in as an admin, I can see all the blogs on the page.  I need it to show for everyone, whether they are logged in as a user or just a visitor to the website.

I have attempted to see if it was a wordpress issue by checking the 'Settings >> Reading' settings and they are set just fine, showing to be 10 posts per page..  It could be something wrong with the loop.  I have the blog pulling from the index.php.

http://www.ilovepennycakes.com/category/blog/

Here is the direct link to the blog not showing in the feed.
http://www.ilovepennycakes.com/thanksgiving-thoughts/

The code is as follows:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

```
<!-- Article Loop -->
<article>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="news-top"></div>
  <div class="news">
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="post-header">
      <h1 class="meander"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
      <p class="likes m500"><?php comments_popup_link( '0', '1', '%' ); ?></p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!--end post header-->
  <!--div class="entry clear"-->
  <div class="blog-content m500">
    <?php if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
  </div>
<!--/div--><!--end entry-->
    <p class="date M500">Posted <?php the_time( 'j M Y' ); ?></p>
    <p class="M500"><?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'pennycakes' ), '<span>', '</span>' ); ?></p>
<!--end post footer-->
  </div><!--end post-->
  </div>
  <div class="news-bottom"></div>
    <?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
    </div><!--end navigation-->
      <div class="navigation index">
      <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older Entries' ); ?></div>
      <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); ?></div>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</article>
<!-- //Article Loop -->
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... are your posts still "Drafts" or published? If they are drafts, it is normal to be able to see them only if you are logged in, because a draft is not published so not supposed to be seen by any visitor. That's my guess. Otherwise, please give more info.

Comment: The post is published and has been.  I updated my question to include the link to the direct post not showing in the feed.  It will show when I'm logged into the Wordpress backend as an admin.  If I go to the blog page, all posts shows.  But it's when I'm not logged in, only one post shows.  That is the problem I am having and I don't know where I went wrong with the coding.

Comment: Please tell me what the name of the page is that you have shown the PHP code from? Was that category.php?

Comment: Yes, the blog's category is set to "blog". It's in "index.php"

Comment: This is probably obvious, it's my first attempt at coding a wordpress website.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have the answer for you: index.php is not the file used to display http://www.ilovepennycakes.com/category/blog/. The file used for this type of archive display is "category.php". If there is no such file in your theme folder, add it (possibly duplicate index.php as you have programmed it or take it from a default example template).